# Django: getting the value of a serializer's field within the serializer itself

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my Django serializer, I have a validate() method.

In it, I want to access the value of one of the serializer's fields. How would I do this?

I'm using Python 3.10.2 and Django 3.2.23.

Previous answers here have suggested using `self.initial_data.get("field_name"))` but that doesn't work for my version of Django (message: AttributeError: 'MySerializer' object has no attribute 'initial_data').

```
class MySerializer:
    models = models.MyModel

    class Meta:
        fields = "my_field"

    def validate(self, data):
        # Want to get the value of my_field here
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `self.initial_data` should work, can you add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `data.get("my_field")` should work.

Comment: @wh0am1: I need to access the data in the serializer, not the data to be verified (passed in the "data" parameter).

Comment: @JPG: Not easily, I'm afraid. It's part of a large, complex system and I don't think I can extract it out easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add data into the associated Django view's context - in my case, an id - and populate it when the serializer is defined.

View:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = ... # Get current db instance here

    serializer = MySerializer(
        instance=instance,
        data=request.data,
        context={"user_id": self.request.user.id},
    )
```

Serializer:

```
def validate(self, data):
    context = getattr(self, "context", None)

    if context is None:
        return data

    user_id = context.get("user_id")
    obj = MyEntity.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
```

This also works for nested serializers: the context value automatically gets supplied for each.